# Can I be in transit in UAE for 4 h without transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, dubai

I am landing in Terminal 1 of Dubai International Airport (DXB). I want to take a bus to Terminal 2 to go to Kish Island. Do I need  transit visa for 4 hours ? (India Nationality)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a visa to transit airside in Dubai airport. An airside transit bus runs between T1, T2 and T3; follow the red Connections signs or ask airport staff for directions.

However, if you travel on separate tickets, you must use the [Marhaba](https://www.marhabaservices.com/) service to transfer any hold baggage you may have. A fee applies for this service.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passengers' travel documents, states in relevant part:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
>   ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They
>   must stay in the international transit area of the airport and
>   have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Passengers transiting through Dubai (DXB) with separate
>     tickets and checked-in baggage do not have to clear
>     immigrations and customs if they use the baggage transfer
>     service offered by the airport. Fees apply.